# Replace a column of text when a button is pressed

Tags: php

Okay so how is this possible to make im not sure what and how to google, so the title is the best thing i could come up with, as a summry.

Here is what i mean.

I have a Disclamer on this Web Site.

Something like this

```
<form method="post" action="introduction.php">

    <table style="height: 100px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">Disclaimer text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr />

    <th scope="row"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" placeholder="Submit" value="Accept"></th>
</form>

<?PHP
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'accept is pressed';
    }
?>
```

So basically..when accept is pressed i want the Disclamer text to dissapear and some other thext should take it's place.

I hope this makes some sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this on only one page or on all your pages?

Comment: Should only happen on this page yes.( If that's the question. )

Comment: Ok, so can this page get reused. In other words do you need to remember that the disclaimer has been accepted?

Comment: And what if the user comes back tomorrow, will they see the disclaimer again or do you want to rememebr for say a month that they have accepted

Comment: Yes, it should be rememberd. (So the text never pops up again)

Comment: I suppose a Month is fine.  (To be remembered)

Comment: So do you want to keep this memory in a database or would a cookie do the trick?

Comment: Yo pokemon, why not using the session?

Comment: @abr Session will only be remembered for the duration of the session, not a month

Comment: Cookies should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a single cookie like this

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    setcookie("GDPR_accepted", 1, time()+(60*60*24*30), '/' );
}

<form method="post" action="introduction.php">
    <table style="height: 100px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<?php
if ( !isset($_COOKIE["GDPR_accepted"]) ) :
?>      
            <td class="align-middle">Disclaimer text</td>
<?php
else:
?>
            <td class="align-middle">OTHER TEXT</td>
<?php
endif;
?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

> But I am not quite sure wht you are putting the other text into a form. But I will let you sort that out :)

Also if cookies are disabled, you will have to change this to store this flag in your database

Comment: It does work, but not on click. only when the site is refreshed. Ps you frogot the closing ?> tag, for the first if-statement.

Comment: Oh I did not get that requirement from your question.

Comment: And you only have a PHP tag on your question! No javascript Tag

Comment: I'm new to this whole thing. Sorry :/